# Програмное изменение атрибутов файлов на "зараженной" флешке

Tags: winapi

Всем добрый день (вечер, утро). Подскажите ответ на такой вопрос: для каждого сисадмина не секрет, что периодически флэшки, после лечения их антивирусом, все-равно не отображают отдельные каталоги и файлы. Их атрибуты, под Win - скрытый... Изменить невозможно. Приходится использовать WinCom или TotalCom. В принципе все нормально - есть соответствующие проги, и больше ничего не надо. Но все-же, какие ф-ии используются для изменения атрибутов "поврежденных" объектов в данных программах? Как это работает? Спасибо за ответ. P.S. Ф-ии WinAPI смотрел.

Answer (score 3):

Выполнить обход всех дирректорий и файлов на диске, включая вложенные и выставить им аттрибуты с помощью API [SetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Пример из msdn, который дает базовое представление:
[Retrieving and Changing File Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)